# Promise executada fora de ordem, como resolver?

Tags: javascript, assincronismo, promises

Estou utilizando a função setTimeout em forma de promise, seguindo o exemplo da documentação da Mozilla. Acontece que a função callback está sendo executada antes do fim do contador, imediatamente após o inicio do programa.

função base:

```
function wait(time) {
  return (
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
  )
}
```

resolução (esta que está dando problema):

```
wait(2000).then(console.log('wating...'))
```

usando async/await funciona normalmente:

```
async function getWait() {
  await wait(2000)
  console.log('wating...')
}

getWait()
```

Answer (score 3):

O `.then` precisa de uma função de callback. Sem a função, o `console.log` é executado imediatamente:

```js
function wait(time) {
  return (
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
  )
}

wait(2000).then( () => {console.log('wating...')})
```

Answer (score 1):

A chamada `then` deve receber uma função (que pode ser anônima)

```
function wait(time) {
  return (
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
  )
}

wait(3000).then(() => console.log('wating 2...'))

async function getWait() {
  await wait(2000)
  console.log('wating 1...')
}
getWait()

console.log("start")
```